# divisor x2 for three hall sensor

Tags: sensor

I would like to increase the performance of a brushless motor by dividing the frequency of the three hall sensors that detect the speed. is it possible to have a scheme to perform?

Comment: Can you explain how you are going to improve performance with this idea?

Comment: Hello! I think that if you can divide the frequency you avoid the protection of the engine, I'm pretty interested in turning it around more.

Comment: @Stefanhack If I understand correctly, you're trying to "trick" the motor controller into thinking the motor is spinning slower than it is so that the driver will drive it harder.  Is this correct?

Comment: Hello! Yes! I think it is possible to make three separate divider circuits for each sensor. do you have any idea which chip I should use to create a square wave?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some understanding. The sensors tell the controller the position of the rotor. This information is used by the controller to switch the phases at the correct time.

The YouTube video [Brushless DC motor animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43JMIuwVrY4) may be of help.

If you divide the frequency the controller will switch the phases at the wrong points and will not run correctly.

Comment: Hello. this was clear to me. but if I do three separate dividers? one for each cable? why should not it work? I have only to halve the frequency, possible that something can not be done?

Comment: Draw your proposed timing diagram of the Hall sensors and the phase switching. Edit your question and add the diagram in.

Comment: Hello. I do not have a scheme. I wanted to prepare it with a cd 4093 and a cd 4013. I would try to put them on the 3 phases of the sensors working at 120 ° and see what happens, I do not think the controller switches the wrong phases, I send a half wave and I think that the phases are not changed .. I just have to try, so I bang my head ...